# how to get file names and paths based on a given attribute in parent tag

Tags: python, xml

I want to change the below code to get `file_names` and `file_paths` only when `fastboot="true"` attribute is present in the parent tag,I provided the current output and expected ouput,can anyone provide guidance on how to do it?

```
import sys
import os
import string
from xml.dom import minidom

if __name__ == '__main__':
    meta_contents = minidom.parse("fast.xml")
    builds_flat = meta_contents.getElementsByTagName("builds_flat")[0]
    build_nodes = builds_flat.getElementsByTagName("build")
    for build in build_nodes:
          bid_name = build.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
          print "Checking if this is cnss related image... : \n"+bid_name.firstChild.data
          if (bid_name.firstChild.data == 'apps'):
             file_names = build.getElementsByTagName("file_name")
             file_paths = build.getElementsByTagName("file_path")
             print "now files paths...\n"
             for fn,fp in zip(file_names,file_paths):
                if (not fp.firstChild.nodeValue.endswith('/')):
                   fp.firstChild.nodeValue = fp.firstChild.nodeValue + '/'
                full_path = fp.firstChild.nodeValue+fn.firstChild.nodeValue
                print "file-to-copy: "+full_path
             break
```

INPUT XML:-

```
  <builds_flat>
    <build>
      <name>apps</name>
      <file_ref ignore="true" minimized="true">
        <file_name>adb.exe</file_name>
        <file_path>LINUX/android/vendor/qcom/proprietary/usb/host/windows/prebuilt/</file_path>
      </file_ref>
      <file_ref ignore="true" minimized="true">
        <file_name>system.img</file_name>
        <file_path>LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/secondary-boot/</file_path>
      </file_ref>
      <download_file cmm_file_var="APPS_BINARY" fastboot_rumi="boot" fastboot="true" minimized="true">
        <file_name>boot.img</file_name>
        <file_path>LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/</file_path>
      </download_file>
      <download_file sparse_image_path="true" fastboot_rumi="abl" fastboot="true" minimized="true">
        <file_name>abl.elf</file_name>
        <file_path>LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/</file_path>
      </download_file>      
    </build>
  </builds_flat>
```

OUTPUT:-

```
...............
now files paths...

file-to-copy: LINUX/android/vendor/qcom/proprietary/usb/host/windows/prebuilt/adb.exe
file-to-copy: LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/secondary-boot/system.img
file-to-copy: LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/boot.img
file-to-copy: LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/abl.elf
```

EXPECTED OUT:-

```
now files paths...

........
file-to-copy: LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/boot.img
file-to-copy: LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/abl.elf
```

Comment: Learn about `xpath`. It will help you to filter html or xml.

Comment: @TammoHeeren - I only want to change this existing code..dont want to use any new modules..can you please provide guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something rather quick and dirty that comes to mind is using the fact that only the `download_file` elements have the `fastboot` attribute, right? If that's the case, you could always get the children of type `download_file` and filter the ones whose `fastboot` attribute is not `"true"`:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

if __name__ == '__main__':
    meta_contents = minidom.parse("fast.xml")
    for elem in meta_contents.getElementsByTagName('download_file'):
        if elem.getAttribute('fastboot') == "true":
            path = elem.getElementsByTagName('file_path')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            file_name = elem.getElementsByTagName('file_name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            print os.path.join(path, file_name)
```

With the sample you provided that outputs:

```
$ python ./stack_034.py
LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/boot.img
LINUX/android/out/target/product/msmcobalt/abl.elf
```

Needless to say... since there's no `.xsd` file (nor that it'd matter with the `minidom`, though) you only get strings (no type safety) and this only applies to the structure shown in the example (you probably would like to add some extra checks there, is what I mean)

**EDIT:**
As per the comment in this answer:

To get the elements within the `<build>` that contains a `<name>` attribute with value `apps`, you can: Find that `<name>` tag (the one whose value is the string `apps`), then move to the parent node (which will put you in the `build` element) and then proceed as mentioned above:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    meta_contents = minidom.parse("fast.xml")
    for elem in meta_contents.getElementsByTagName('name'):
        if elem.firstChild.nodeValue == "apps":
            apps_build = elem.parentNode
            for elem in apps_build.getElementsByTagName('download_file'):
                if elem.getAttribute('fastboot') == "true":
                    path = elem.getElementsByTagName('file_path')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                    file_name = elem.getElementsByTagName('file_name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                    print os.path.join(path, file_name)
```

Comment: there can be multipe `<build>` elements in the xml,we need to get the one for 'apps'